# How i can get all att "href" of elements by 1 className? js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

As example i have code:

```
<a class="link" href="https://example1.com">example1</a>
<a class="link" href="https://example2.com">example2</a>
<a class="link" href="https://example3.com">example3</a>
```

Need get all attribute "href" of elementh with class "link"
Example output:

```
https://example1.com
https://example2.com
https://example3.com
```

I have script, but it always get 1st element:

```
let i = 0;
let b = 3;
while (i < 3) { 
var href = $('.link').attr('href');
  console.log(href);
  i++;
}
```

How i can switch at the next element ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you keep selecting the same element. You could get all the items first and store them in an array. Then you can use a loop to iterate over your array and do something with all the links.

Here's how I'd do it in JavaScript:

```js
let links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");

for (let i = 0; i > links; i++) {
  let href = links[i].getAttribute("href");
  console.log(href);
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="https://example1.com">example1</a>
<a class="link" href="https://example2.com">example2</a>
<a class="link" href="https://example3.com">example3</a>
```